# Calculating the derivative of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus

If $v(y) = \frac{dy}{dt}$ then what is $\frac{dv}{dy}$

Comment: You are mixing notations there, first with Leibniz's $\frac{dy}{dt}$ then with Lagrange's $v'$. The question is therefore not clear. Could you rewrite this with just one notation? Leibniz's would probably be best.

Comment: Does $v'$ in this case mean $\frac{dv}{dy}$ or $\frac{dv}{dt}$?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{d}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dt}}  \frac{d}{dt} $$

so 
$$\frac{dv}{dy} =  \frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)= \frac{ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} }{\frac{dy}{dt}} $$

Comment: or equivalently $\dfrac{\frac{dv}{dt}}{ v}$,  both of which might be read as acceleration divided by velocity